# How to wait for function with observable to resolve?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

Working on Angular/Angular2 and I've got something like

```
buildData() {
this.services.getData()).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe(response => {
        this.handleResponse(response);
})


handleEvent($event) {
const value = this.value;
this.buildData();
//Do some stuff here after buildData is finished. 
}
```

What I don't know is how to wait until buildData() finishes.

I tried adding an await

```
handleEvent($event) {
const value = this.value;
await this.buildData();
//Do some stuff here after buildData is finished. 
}
```

But it doesn't work since it doesnt return a promise.

Comment: `rxjs` often requires a shift to reactive code rather than imperative code. So a working but likely bad answer would be don't subscribe, return the observable, use tap pipe operator to call handleResponse as a side effect and do `this.buildData().subscribe((data)=> {do some stuff})` in handleEvent. Would need details of `handleResponse` and what the *do some stuff* is to properly advise though

Comment: Pay attention because, differently from Promises, Observable can emit several values over time

Comment: Something like this? `concatMap(i => from(this.handleEvent(i)))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a pipe with the [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator to trigger your side effect  then return the observable so you can subscribe on it later or trigger other side effects from it

```js
buildData() {
  return this.services.getData()).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .pipe(
      tap((data) => this.handleResponse(response))
    );
})


handleEvent($event) {
  const value = this.value;
  this.buildData()
    .pipe(
      //your operations
    ).subscribe();
}
```